# How to create a wrapper library without exposing the underlying library being used?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

Using Cmake I would like to know how to create a wrapper library and let the users link their application with this library only. Users don't need to specify the original library in their linker flags.

For instance, I create a wrapper library for libwebsockets, named libcustomws.

```
add_library(customws main.c)
target_link_libraries(customws websockets)
```

I would like user (with no libwebsockets installed) to be able to do:

```
add_executable(user_app user_app.c)
target_link_libraries(user_app customws pthread)
```

Comment: "with no libwebsockets installed" - doesn't that mean the `user_app` executable won't be able to compile?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper libraries without any additional code from within your project can best be implemented with small `INTERFACE` library targets with the `IMPORTED` tag. Example for your scenario:

```
add_library(customws INTERFACE IMPORTED)

target_include_directories(customws
    INTERFACE
    /some/include/path)

target_link_libraries(customws
    INTERFACE
    websockets)
```

This way, targets that use this library can just

```
add_executable(user_app user_app.c)
target_link_libraries(user_app customws pthread)
```

and get the usage requirements from the target `customws`, in this case an include directory and a linked library (`websockets`) are *propagated* through `customws`. This can be a good thing, as it might encapsulate implementation details of the dependency (different flags for different platforms etc.).

If you like to automatically link to compiled code (that is part of your project), this can be easily done by adding a small intermediate `OBJECT` library, e.g.

```
add_libraray(customwsenhanced
    OBJECT
    someCode.c)

target_link_library(customwsenhanced
    PUBLIC
    customws)
```

Depending on whether `someCode.c` depends on the usage requirements of `customws`, the `target_link_library` for `customwsenhanced` could also use `INTERFACE` propagation. Now, a client application can go with

```
add_executable(user_app user_app.c)
target_link_libraries(user_app customwsenhanced pthread)
```

and will get both the compiled object code of `someCode.c` as well as flags etc. from `customws`.